# check if two objects are both undefined or null in javascript

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, logical-operators

I have a method hitTest that check for collision detection and can return a Point object (if a collision is happened) or (if there is no collision) it returns `null` or `undefined` (i haven't deeply understand when it return null or undefined but i trust chrome console).

I have to test collision on 2 objects. And check if one or the two collisions are happening. I have tried this code:

```
var result1 = hitTest(player, object1);
var result2 = hitTest(player, object2);
if( result1 || result2 )  { blabla() };
```

but it doesn't work.

now.. i know that js is reallly a tricky language and i think about a smart way to do this without writing `typeof` 4 times. I'm thinking about python short-circuit logical operators...

Comment: `||` returns the first found `true`, and `false` if not `true ` found. `&&` returns the first found `false`, and `true` if not `false` found.

Comment: thanks. add it as answer and i can use it as right answer

Comment: Do you want your if statement to be true if there are (0, at least 1, 2) collisions?

Comment: i wanto my if pass if at least 1 is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `&&`, it returns the first detected `false/null/undefined/0`, i.e. `if` won't pass, if either `result1` or `result2` is `null`.

Comment: A better way to say this is: 

For `&&` to pass, BOTH have to be `true`. For `||` to pass, only one has to be `true`.

Comment: @krillgar Yep, if we were talking about `if`. I was talking about `&&` operator, which really returns either of its operands. Though fixed the answer, since `if` itself is not failing...

Answer (score 1):

for this type of thing, underscore.js is beautifull:  http://underscorejs.org/#isNull  and  http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined

I use these helpers frequently to get around edge cases in JS such as the ones you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need to write `typeof` 4 times already but anyway;

Coercion paradigm for conditional statements and operators:

```
//TYPE           //RESULT
Undefined        // false
Null             // false
Boolean          // The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
Number           // The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
String           // The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
Object           // true
```

From Mozilla:

**Logical AND (`&&`)**

> **expr1 && expr2**
>   *If the first operand (`expr1`) can be converted to `false`, the `&&` operator returns `false` rather than the value of `expr1`.*

**Logical OR (`||`)**

> **expr1 || expr2**
>   *Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns true if either operand is `true`; if both are `false`, returns `false`.*

```js
true || false // returns true
true || true // returns true
false || true // returns true
false || false // returns false
"Cat" || "Dog"     // returns Cat
false || "Cat"     // returns Cat
"Cat" || false     // returns Cat

true && false // returns false
true && true // returns true
false && true // returns false
false && false // returns false
"Cat" && "Dog" // returns Dog
false && "Cat" // returns false
"Cat" && false // returns false
```

Additionally, you can use a shortcut `isset()` method just like in PHP to properly validate your objects:

```js
function isSet(value) {
    return typeof(value) !== 'undefined' && value != null;
}
```

So; your code would be:

```js
var result1 = hitTest(player, object1),
    result2 = hitTest(player, object2);
if ( isSet(result1) && isSet(result2) )  { blabla(); };
```